# Find a formula for the $nth$ non-square positive integer, in terms of $n.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let $x_n$ be the nth non- square positive integer. Then $x_1=2,x_2=3,x_3=5,x_4=6,$ etc. For a positive real number $x,$ denote the integer closest to it by $\langle x\rangle.$ If $x=m+0.5,$ where $m$ is an integer, then define $\langle x\rangle=m.$ For example, $\langle 1.2\rangle=1,$ $\langle 2.8\rangle=3,$ $\langle 3.5\rangle=3.$ Show that $x_n=n+\langle \sqrt n\rangle .$

I attemted to use induction to solve this but I was not so lucky to solve it. I am now enervated with all my futile travalis. Here is the brief elaboration of my approach to this problem:

> We can easily verify this statement for $x_1$. Now, if we assume this to be true for $n=k$, we formulate our induction hypothesis as $x_k=k+\langle \sqrt k\rangle .$ Now, if $n=k+1$ then we must have, $x_{k+1}=k+1+\langle \sqrt {k+1}\rangle .$

Now, this becomes hard to prove. Then I proceeded further as follows:

> The next number of $x_k$ might be a square. When this is the case, then $\exists n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x_k+1=n^2$. This means $x_k=n^2-1.$ So, $n+1|x_k$ and $n-1|x_k$. We observe, $$d=\text{gcd}(n+1,n-1)=1\space \text{or}\space 2.$$ If $n$ is even then $d=2$ is never possible. If $n$ is odd,$d$ might actually be equal to $2.$ But then, $x_k$ is even.

But again, I am stuck here. I dont get how to proceed further. The problem  looks uncanny in some sense to me. But I really have no idea on what to do next? I am vacillating a lot with this problem, but as of yet, haven't encountered any acceptable or elegant approach. Is there any standard way, to solve these sort of problems ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be any positive integer.

Let $a=<\sqrt{n}>$. As the nearest integer $|\sqrt{n}-a|\leq 0.5$.

Rearranging that:
$$ a-0.5 \leq \sqrt{n} \leq a+0.5$$

Squaring:
$$ a^2 - a + 0.25 \leq n \leq a^2 + a + .25$$

Adding $a$ and loosening some of the inequalities gives:

$$ a^2 < n + a  < a^2 +2a +1=(a+1)^2$$

Thus, $a^2$ is the largest square less than $n + a$ (with $n+a$ itself being non-square), so the number of squares that are at most $n+a$ is $a$, so $n+a=n+<\sqrt{n}>$ is the $n$th non-square.

Comment: Thanks! But I dont get, how do you assert this  "so $n+a=n+<\sqrt{n}>$ is the $n$th non-square. "?

Comment: There are $n+a$ numbers from 1 to $n+a$. $a$ of them are squares, so $n$ of them are non-squares. $n+a$ itself is a non-square, so as the last of those $n$ non-squares, it’s the $n$th non-square.

Comment: But how do you know, that $n+a$ is the last of those, $nth$ non-square ?

Comment: Because it’s bigger than all the other numbers from 1 to $n+a$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now. This is indeed a beautiful and an elegant explanation !